# pgfkeys - .is family handler

Tags: pgfkeys

This might seem a trivial question, but not for someone wanting to understand **pgfkeys** very well. In the following definition from pgfkeys package, why can't the `\edef` be replaced by `\def`? I have asked a pgfkeys master this question before but apparently he didn't get the question correctly, since I mixed it with other issues.

```
\pgfkeys{%
    /handlers/.is family/.code=
    \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.ecode=
      \edef\noexpand\pgfkeysdefaultpath{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/}
    }
}
```

The following gives me the same result even as `\edef` is replaced by `\def`. Am I right?

```
\pgfkeys{%
    /handlers/.is family/.code=
    \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.ecode=
      \def\noexpand\pgfkeysdefaultpath{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/}
    }
}

\def\firstlayerfam{/fam/subfam}
\def\secondlayerfam{\firstlayerfam}
\def\family{\secondlayerfam}

\pgfkeys{
  \family/.is family,
  \family % This changes the path even without '.cd'. OK!
}
```

**EDIT**

The reason I see is in the following

```
\long\def\pgfkeys@unpack#1=#2=#3\pgfkeys@stop{%
  \pgfkeys@spdef\pgfkeyscurrentkey{#1}%
   % The following \edef is crucial. In fact, it should come before the last line
   % (ie, before calling the Carlisle despacer \pgfkeys@spdef). Because if #1 is
   % a macro, the content may be the one that carries spurious leading and 
   % trailing spaces. Without expansion, \pgfkeys@add@path@as@needed may even add 
   % default path when it isn't needed. See below.
   \edef\pgfkeyscurrentkey{\pgfkeyscurrentkey}%
   \ifx\pgfkeyscurrentkey\pgfkeys@empty%
    % Skip
  \else
    \pgfkeys@add@path@as@needed
    \pgfkeys@spdef\pgfkeyscurrentvalue{#2}%
    \ifx\pgfkeyscurrentvalue\pgfkeysnovalue@text% Hmm... no value
      \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@def}%
      {\pgfkeysgetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@def}{\pgfkeyscurrentvalue}}%
      {}% no default, so leave it
    \fi%
    \ifx\pgfkeyscurrentvalue\pgfkeysvaluerequired%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/errors/value required/.@cmd}%
       \pgfkeyscurrentkey\pgfkeyscurrentvalue\pgfeov%
    \else%
      \pgfkeys@case@one%
    \fi%
  \fi
}
```

Trace log:

```
{changing \pgfkeyscurrentkey=macro:->\family /.is family}
{into \pgfkeyscurrentkey=macro:->//fam/subfam/.is family}
```

Comment: Like you, I don't see the need for `\edef` here as there is `.ecode`. I suspect this is a 'historical oversight': if you read `pgfkeys` you find a few of these. (When I wrote `l3keys`, basing it on `pgfkeys`, I had a lot of 'fun' as a result.)

Answer (score 5):

It's clear (without ever having used pgfkeys) that `edef` and `def` are almost certainly the same in that context.

If

```
  \edef\noexpand\pgfkeysdefaultpath{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/}
```

works then presumably it *doesn't* define `\noexpand` but rather the `\noexpand` is preventing expansion of `\pgfkeysdefaultpath`. This tells you the whole line is being put through an expansion context (almost certainly edef) and if it is edef then the definition of the macro will already have been expanded *before* the definition, so `\edef` and `\def` will give the same result.

Comment: The `.ecode` handler uses `\edef`, so the code here is essentially 'inside an `\edef`'.

Comment: @JosephWright: `.ecode` operates on the current value of the key, when the "code" (i.e., callback) of the key is being defined, and not when the key is set later. So the crucial point is the `\edef` in the code I have annotated with `crucial` in the edit to my question.

Comment: @AhmedMusa I was trying to highlight why there is a `\noexpand` here: as you say, `.ecode` does expansion when defining the key. As I've commented on the question, the 'explicit' (point of use) `\edef` looks redundant to me.